# How to store multiple lines in a file with python?

Tags: python-3.x

How to write to a file in python3 in such a way that your new input gets stored in the same file but on a new line and if you use append mode it writes this new input without spaces.

```py
def register():
    with open('username.txt', mode='a')as user_file:
        username = input('Enter Username : ')
        user_file.write(f"{username}\n")
    with open('password.txt', mode='a')as pass_file:
        password = input('Enter Password: ')
        pass_file.write(f'{password}\n')
def login() :
    with open('username.txt', mode='r')as user_file:
        validate_u = user_file.readlines()
    with open('password.txt', mode='r')as pass_file:
        validate_p = pass_file.readlines()
    l_user = input('Username: ')
    l_pass = input('Password: ')
    if l_user == validate_u and l_pass == validate_p:
        print('Login successful')
    else:
        print('login failed')
import Enigma_Register
import Enigma_login

print('1-Login\n2-Register')
choice = int(input("enter choice: "))
if choice == 1:
    Enigma_login.login()

elif choice == 2:
    Enigma_Register.register()
    Enigma_login.login()
else:
    print('Invalid Choice!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write to a file appending the spaces or putting line endings in write.
Here is an example with line endings:

```
myinput = input('input number: ')
with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('{}\n'.format(myinput))
```

Comment: one more thing if you want to validate this using regular expressions for eg:if there is lets say a password file and it has multiple passwords stored on it if we want to validate those we can use .readlines or is there another way to do this?

Comment: but if want to validate if username and password are both incorrect or one of them is incorrect for me i used if else statements and using (and) and (or) conditionals but it results in a bug it only executes one of the condition where both username and password don't exist in the files

Comment: so here is the code i use to register:def register():
    with open('username.txt', mode='a')as user_file:
        username = input('Enter Username : ')
        user_file.write(f"{username}\n")
    with open('password.txt', mode='a')as pass_file:
        password = input('Enter Password: ')
        pass_file.write(f'{password}\n')

Comment: here is the code for login:def login() :
    with open('username.txt', mode='r')as user_file:
        validate_u = user_file.readlines()
    with open('password.txt', mode='r')as pass_file:
        validate_p = pass_file.readlines()
    l_user = input('Username: ')
    l_pass = input('Password: ')
    if l_user == validate_u and l_pass == validate_p:
        print('Login successful')
    else:
        print('login failed')

Comment: and finally here is the code for main file:import Enigma_Register
import Enigma_login

print('1-Login\n2-Register')
choice = int(input("enter choice: "))
if choice == 1:
    Enigma_login.login()

elif choice == 2:
    Enigma_Register.register()
    Enigma_login.login()
else:
    print('Invalid Choice!')

Comment: When you do the command `readlines`from files it returns a list. In your case you are comparing a string with a list. That's why you are receiving the error, you have to iterate over each line and compare with your login and password.

Comment: so i should use a loop to iterate over each line in passwords and usernames files thats what you are saying!

Comment: thanks a lot i hope u don't mind i asked a lot of questions!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding /n at the last.

Such as

f.write( "I am a boy /n")
f.write("I am a student /n")

Comment: /n is use for new line